# Javascript replace not working for some reason

Tags: javascript

Trying to remove ST,+ from this string below. I've tried so many different ways but just can't seem to get it to remove anything from the string at all. Anything I'm doing wrong?

```
function convertSerialData(valueIn){

valueIn.replace(/ST/i, ''); 

return valueIn;
}

alert(convertSerialData('ST,+00.8  g '));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't seem to be assigning the results of the replace:

`valueIn = valueIn.replace(/ST,[+]/i, '');`

Or, more concisely:

```
function convertSerialData(valueIn){
    return valueIn.replace(/ST,[+]/i, ''); 
}
```

Comment: While this does fix the issue of not returning the value, it still does not do what the OP wants, which is to remove `ST,+`

Answer (score 6):

`valueIn.replace(/ST/i, '');` doesn't modify the string, it returns a new one.  You need to use the value returned from the `.replace()` function.

Also, if you want to remove more than just `ST`, then you just need to update your regex to remove the characters you need.

```
function convertSerialData(valueIn){
    return valueIn.replace(/ST,\+/i, '');
}
```

Comment: While this does fix the issue of not returning the value, it still does not do what the OP wants, which is to remove `ST,+`

Comment: @Archer: Thanks, must've missed that in the question.